Proving that $\sum{a_k}$ converges $\implies$ $\sum{a_k^2}$ converges as well
With this question, I am aware that the left hand side of the implication implies $a_k\to 0$ and the right hand side implies $a_k^2\to 0$. Is the original question then equivalent to proving $a_k\to 0\implies a_k^2\to 0$? Here, $a_k \geq 0 \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ Any advice will be much appreciated.

Where did this question come from, please

Are you missing a condition that $a_k\ge 0$ for all $k$?

yes, that's right... my mistake, i forgot to write that in...

Terms going to zero isn't enough to imply series convergence. I bet this question is a duplicate, though.

Hint: Find a value $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that you can use the Comparison Test for convergence on the subseries $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=K}^\infty a_k^2 < \sum_{k=K}^\infty a_k$$

thanks for the tip
